# how I write a windows service to manage other windows service?(can I?)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I want to write window service which manages another window service and checks if it is stopped or running.

If it is stopped then my root service starts service again.

My root service is running at a certain times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a windows Service which monitors your service . The code in your service will be

```
 var Service = new ServiceController(servicetowach);
                    if (Service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running
                        && Service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
                    {
Service.Start();
}
```

Where ServiceToWatch is the name of the service you want to watch if running or not

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class:

> Represents a Windows service and allows you to connect to a running or
>   stopped service, manipulate it, or get information about it.

---

**Example:**

To start a service, you would use code like this:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("YourServiceName");
service.Start()
```

---

The class has a [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status.aspx) property which you can use to check if the service you want to monitor is running or stopped.

---

**Alternative:**

You can also use command line tools to check/start/stop services.

To check if a service is running:

```
sc query YourServiceName
```

To start a service:

```
net start YourServiceName
```

To stop a service:

```
net stop YourServiceName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control other services using the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class.